# Ruby: Color-coded stack trace

Tags: ruby, exception, logging, syntax-highlighting, stack-trace

Here's a neat [color-coded stack trace](http://java.dzone.com/articles/filtering-stack-trace-hell) for Java. Does anyone have ideas on how to get something like this for Ruby?

[image: stacktrace]

Comment: The first idea that popped into my mind was to use regex101.com with a specialized pattern, like this: https://regex101.com/r/eG9hQ8/1. Of couse, if you use this very often you should find/build a tool to automatically color the output.